# Why is margin default not 0 in this case?

Tags: html, css

I have a div positioned absolutely and then a `ul` element inside it. For some `ul` is not taking margin: 0 as default.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  display: block;
}
.userinfo {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: default;
}
.userinfo .sprite {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  right: 21px;
  bottom: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.userinfo .sprite ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.userinfo .sprite ul .themes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 14px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif") -23px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.userinfo .sprite ul .user_lang {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif") -23px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="userinfo" href="#">


  <div class="sprite">
    <ul>
      <li class="themes"></li>
      <li class="user_lang"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</a>
```

My question is, why is margin for `ul` element not 0?

Comment: Default browser css apply, you can use reset css 
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margins are defined by default, unless specified, by your browser.

For example here is the webkit default styling: [Default webkit styling](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)

What you need to do in order to fix that is to explicitly declare the margins to a value of 0px. 
Also something like [this CSS snippet](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) might help you getting all that sorted.

Answer (score 0):

By default Ul has margin and padding you need to reset it

```css
* {
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  display: block;
}
.userinfo {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: default;
}
.userinfo .sprite {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 35px;
  right: 21px;
  bottom: 8px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.userinfo .sprite ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 15px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.userinfo .sprite ul .themes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 13px;
  height: 14px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif") -23px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.userinfo .sprite ul .user_lang {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif") -23px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a class="userinfo" href="#">


  <div class="sprite">
    <ul>
      <li class="themes"></li>
      <li class="user_lang"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</a>
```